# How to export data values on terminal to CSV file in Bash

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I would like to export the data values generated  on Terminal into CSV file, following is the output that i obtain after executing an instruction in Freesurfer

```
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:~$ mri_segstats --subject Sub1 --etiv-only

    $Id: mri_segstats.c,v 1.75.2.9 2013/02/16 00:09:33 greve Exp $
    cwd 
    cmdline mri_segstats --subject Sub1 --etiv-only 
    sysname  Linux
    hostname dev-OptiPlex-780
    machine  x86_64
    user     dev
    UseRobust  0
    atlas_icv (eTIV) = 1144730 mm^3    (det: 1.701803 )
```

From the above output ,I would like to extract the only the value of atlas_ICV(eTIV) (i.e = 1144730 mm^3) in a csv file using bash script ,any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have written automated code for extracting ICV value for 10 subjects that i have in my directory

```
    for ICV in `cat list_subjects.txt`;do

    #mri_segstats --subject $ICV --etiv-only

   ICV_Calculation=mri_segstats --subject $ICV --etiv-only | sed -n 's/.*(eTIV) = \([0-9].*mm^3\).*/\1/p'

    echo "${Subjects_ICV},${ICV_Calculation}" >>Subjects_ICV.csv

    done
```

where list_subjects.txt includes all the subjects that i have in my directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to extract the only the value of `atlas_ICV (eTIV)` (i.e =
>   `1144730 mm^3`)

Given this file:

```
: mri_segstats.c,v 1.75.2.9 2013/02/16 00:09:33 greve Exp $
cwd 
cmdline mri_segstats --subject Sub1 --etiv-only 
sysname  Linux
hostname dev-OptiPlex-780
machine  x86_64
user     dev
UseRobust  0
atlas_icv (eTIV) = 1144730 mm^3    (det: 1.701803 )
```

I can use this `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*(eTIV) = \([0-9].*mm^3\).*/\1/p' atlas
1144730 mm^3
```

If you want to extract that value from output to `STDOUT`, just use a pipe, like so:

```
cat atlas | sed -n 's/.*(eTIV) = \([0-9].*mm^3\).*/\1/p'
1144730 mm^3
```

In your case I guess it would look like:

```
mri_segstats --subject Sub1 --etiv-only | sed -n 's/.*(eTIV) = \([0-9].*mm^3\).*/\1/p'
```

---

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

Comment: I have small question The --subject Sub1 denotes only one subject, i have 10 subjects , how could i possibly run mri_segstats instruction for 10 subjects and extract ICV for each accordingly ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea, I don't know what `mri_segstats` is!

Comment: mri_segstats is an normal instruction, when i install freesurfer -Brain imaging software, mri_segstats represents the statistical information after the MRI has undergone segmentation, i have written the code for segmentation and it calculates ICV values, I have 10 subjects and when i run the code mrisegstats on each subjects it generates ICV value, but i want an automated code ( like a for loop which can all subjects and generate ICV value). I have updated the code that i have written in the question ,please check